# Why is this categorized as a MIDI device (G10H1/0066), as the patent is from 1897?

Tags: meta-data, categorization

The categorization for this patent reads: "G10H1/0066 - Transmission between separate instruments or between individual components of a musical system using a MIDI interface."

The patent is from 1897.

MIDI was first released in 1983.

Comment: Which patent are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the patent you are referring to - [US580035](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/d8/63/b2/7644905570595a/US580035.pdf). Its title is "ART OF AND APPARATUS FOR GENERATING AND DISTRIBUTING MUSIC ELECTRICALLY."

No, it does not use MIDI, but if you were looking for prior art in a MIDI related case you might be interested in unearthing this document. Google patents advanced get hits on a half-a-dozen others from before MIDI existed.

I think   [G10H1/0033](https://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/cpc-G10H.html#G10H1/0033):  . Recording/reproducing or transmission of music for electrophonic musical instruments (of accompaniment G10H1/361) would have been a better classification.

Comment: +1 for making the effort to track down the patent.

Comment: Hello George, many thanks for your reply. And also many apologies for missing your message yesterday. I am not used to the interface and somehow assumed that the patent # would be added to the message.

Comment: @mjkhoo - thanks for posting here. I assume you got to this site via the "Discuss" link on google patents.  That set up does get us participants and, at one point, seemed to sometimes include the number. The other shortcoming of that link is no SE site is a discussion site. All are fairly strictly Q & A.

Comment: I am also not used to having return post a message ... Anyway this is a very interesting point you make. - One comment in reply is that Cahill's machine (US580035) is sometimes seen as an early ancestor of the Hammond Organ (US 1956350) and the latter is classified as "G10H3/00 - Instruments in which the tones are generated by electromechanical means." Both inventions use a type of alternator (sorry I am not an engineer) to generate AC electric current of different frequencies corresponding to tones and harmonics. So G10H3/00 is also a possibility.

Comment: I think there is a good argument that it is electromechanical. But within G10H3, I'm not sure.  But there might be an argument for 3/08 as the machine appears to use electromagnetic induction. The Hammond organ patent uses /02 /03 and /12. Okay just saw your comment! - that is enough discussion from me. Many thanks again!

Comment: @mjkhoo - one feature of the SE sites is the OP has the option of selecting an answer as the accepted answer. Feel free to wait a few days to see if you get an answer you like better, but a another feature of SE sites is any question which does not get an accepted answer annoyingly keeps coming around ever few months. The answerer get reputation points if their answer is accepted. (I don't need the points, just being educational about the sites.)